# About CollectionView Deselect the SelectedItem

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.uwp

How to deselect the SelectedItem if the selected item does not meet the requirement using the collection view? Do I have to create a custom collection view? How to do on the override the OnPropertyChanged method? Thank you.

Comment: set `SelectedItem` to null

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide some code and more context.  What does "does not meet the requirement" mean?  There are a number of ways this could be done; the best way is going to depend on what specifically you're trying to do.

Comment: does not meet the requirement means that I don't want to hightlight the selected item although the user select the item. For example, I have a list of orders, and I tried to merge the order, but only the orders which have different order number can be merged. So when user selects one order on on collection view, i want to stop him from selecting the other order from the other collection view. Even though when he selects order with the same order number, I don't want to highlight the selected item. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can `deselecte` the `SelectedItem` in the `CollectionView_SelectionChanged` event:

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    //var previous = e.PreviousSelection;
    //var current = e.CurrentSelection;

    CollectionView collectionV = sender as CollectionView;

    if ()//meet requirement
    {

    }
    else
    {
        //not meet requirement
        collectionV.SelectedItem = null;

    }
}
```

And in xaml:

```
<CollectionView SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged" SelectionMode="Single">
    <CollectionView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
            <x:String>Baboon</x:String>
            <x:String>Capuchin Monkey</x:String>
            <x:String>Blue Monkey</x:String>
        </x:Array>
    </CollectionView.ItemsSource>
</CollectionView>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using MVVM design pattern, then you should be able to track the `CollectionView`'s `SelectedItem` property in your `ViewModel`, essentially using Binding in `TwoWay` mode. Here is the sample:

YourView.xaml:

`<CollectionView ItemsSource="Items" SelectedItem="SelectedItem"/>`

YourViewModel.cs

```
public IList<string> Items{get;set;}
private string _selectedItem;
public string SelectedItem
{
  get=>_selectedItem;
  set
    {
      //if selected item is the same one, return
      if(Equals(value,_selectedItem)) return;
    
      //if the item doesn't meet the requirement, don't update the selected item in the view model
      if(!ItemMeetsYourRequirement(value))
      {
        //raise property changed to notify view to change the selected item to previous one
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem));
        return;
      }
      //if you are here, the selected item is changed and meets your requirements;
      _selectedItem = value;
      OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItem);
    }
} 

private bool ItemMeetsYourRequirement(string item) => return true; //add your logic here
```

Answer (score 0):

Working algorithm upon https://stackoverflow.com/a/64457513/1894630 solution:

```
private void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    CollectionView collectionV = sender as CollectionView;
    Viewmodels.Slotviewmodel current;
    if (e.CurrentSelection.Count == 0 || e.PreviousSelection.Count == 0)
    {
        if (e.CurrentSelection.Count != 0)
        {
            current = e.CurrentSelection[0] as Viewmodels.Slotviewmodel;
            if (!current.available)
            {
                collectionV.SelectedItem = null;
            }
        }
        return;
    }
    current = e.CurrentSelection[0] as Viewmodels.Slotviewmodel;
    if (!current.available) //meet requirement
    {
        collectionV.SelectedItem = e.PreviousSelection[0];
    }
}
```